# Pulp add new constraint where options/types cannot be the same?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, mathematical-optimization, pulp

The code below allows me to optimize profits based on a budget(max_cost) and picks (max_to_pick) allowed. How do I go about adding a new constraint where I cannot pick the same city.

```
from pulp import *

  # PROBLEM DATA:
  costs = [15, 25, 35, 40, 45, 55]
  profits = [1.7, 2, 2.4, 3.2, 5.6, 6.2]
  # city = ["NYC","SF","LA","SF","NYC","LA"]   NEW CONSTRAINTS
  max_cost = 200
  max_to_pick = 4

  # DECLARE PROBLEM OBJECT:
  prob = LpProblem("Mixed Problem", LpMaximize)

  # VARIABLES
  n = len(costs)
  N = range(n)
  x = LpVariable.dicts('x', N, cat="Binary")

  # OBJECTIVE
  prob += lpSum([profits[i]*x[i] for i in N])

  # CONSTRAINTS
  prob += lpSum([x[i] for i in N]) <= max_to_pick        # Limit number to include
  prob += lpSum([x[i]*costs[i] for i in N]) <= max_cost  # Limit max. cost

  # SOLVE & PRINT RESULTS
  prob.solve()
  print(LpStatus[prob.status])
  print('Profit = ' + str(value(prob.objective)))
  print('Cost = ' + str(sum([x[i].varValue*costs[i] for i in N])))

  for v in prob.variables ():
  print (v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to limit the choices such that the cities in list `city` are included at most once, then adding the constraints as follows should do this. It sets a constraint so that the sum of `x` decision variables allocated to each city is at most 1.

There may be a more pythonic way to create the list indexes. You could create all of them in a one liner as follows, but I'd find it harder to follow:

`list_of_lists_of_indices = [[i for i in N if city[i] == c] for c in set(city)]`

```
from pulp import *
# PROBLEM DATA:
costs = [15, 25, 35, 40, 45, 55]
profits = [1.7, 2, 2.4, 3.2, 5.6, 6.2]
city = ["NYC","SF","LA","SF","NYC","LA"] # NEW CONSTRAINTS

max_cost = 200
max_to_pick = 4
# DECLARE PROBLEM OBJECT:
prob = LpProblem("Mixed Problem", LpMaximize)
# VARIABLES
n = len(costs)
N = range(n)
x = LpVariable.dicts('x', N, cat="Binary")
# OBJECTIVE
prob += lpSum([profits[i]*x[i] for i in N])
# CONSTRAINTS
prob += lpSum([x[i] for i in N]) <= max_to_pick        # Limit number to include
prob += lpSum([x[i]*costs[i] for i in N]) <= max_cost  # Limit max. cost

# NEW CONSTRAINT
for c in set(city):
  index_list = [i for i in N if city[i] == c]
  prob += lpSum([x[i] for i in index_list]) <= 1

# SOLVE & PRINT RESULTS
prob.solve()
print(LpStatus[prob.status])
print('Profit = ' + str(value(prob.objective)))
print('Cost = ' + str(sum([x[i].varValue*costs[i] for i in N])))

for v in prob.variables ():
    print (v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

Comment: wow. Thank you so much again! btw is there a way to add the cities chosen? For v in prob.variables ():
    print (v.name, "=", v.varValue) is there a way to put that into a dictionary of the cost, profit and city chosen?

Comment: Nae bother. `cities_chosen = [city[i] for i in N if x[i].varValue > 0.5]`. If you then do `print('cities chosen: ', cities_chosen)` will print the included cities.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the code below easier to follow because it doesn't rely on indexes and lists of indexes.

The key to this approach is that you can use an object as a dictionary key.

So the variables dictionary (here, x) is comprised of key-value pairs of Facility object, LPVariable.

```
from pulp import *

class Facility():

    def __init__(self, cost, profit, city):
        self.cost = cost
        self.profit = profit
        self.city = city

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Facility(city={self.city}, profit={self.profit}, cost={self.cost})" 


# PROBLEM DATA:
max_cost = 200
max_to_pick = 4

costs = [15, 25, 35, 40, 45, 55]
profits = [1.7, 2, 2.4, 3.2, 5.6, 6.2]
cities = ["NYC","SF","LA","SF","NYC","LA"] 

facilities = [Facility(cost, profit, city) for cost, profit, city in
              zip(costs, profits, cities)]


# DECLARE PROBLEM OBJECT:
prob = LpProblem("Mixed Problem", LpMaximize)

# VARIABLES
x = LpVariable.dicts('facility', facilities, cat="Binary")

# OBJECTIVE
prob += lpSum([facility.profit * x[facility] for facility in facilities])

# CONSTRAINTS
# number of facilities
prob += lpSum(x.values()) <= max_to_pick # Limit number to include

# maximum cost
prob += lpSum([facility.cost * x[facility] for facility in facilities]) <= max_cost

# no city more than once
# loop through unique city names
# add a constraint that the sum of matching facilities <= 1
unique_cities = set([facility.city for facility in facilities])
for city in unique_cities:
    prob += lpSum([x[facility] for facility in facilities if facility.city == city]) <= 1

# solve the problem
prob.solve()

# identify the chosen facilities
# object_variable_d swaps keys and values
# so you can find the Facility object from the LpVariable
# all of the LpVariables are unique, so this should work
object_variable_d = {v: k for k, v in x.items()}
chosen_facilities = [object_variable_d[var] 
                     for var in prob.variables() 
                     if var.value() == 1]

# print out results
print(LpStatus[prob.status])
print(f'Profit = {value(prob.objective)}')
print(f'Cost = {sum([facility.cost for facility in chosen_facilities])}')
for facility in chosen_facilities:
    print(facility)
```